# Where can I find SRTM DSMs (digital surface model)?

Tags: data, remote-sensing, imagery, srtm, dem

I'm interested in finding a 30 meter DSM (digital surface model that includes canopy) from SRTM with the hope of creating a 30 meter canopy height model. I know that it can be done because the following studies have:

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Le_Pierce/publication/223834023_Vegetation_height_estimation_from_Shuttle_Radar_Topography_Mission_and_National_Elevation_Datasets/links/02e7e536253c3d0b74000000.pdf

and
http://www2.fiu.edu/~serp1/projects/jpl/jpl.pdf

However, I can't for the life of me find DSMs, only DEMs.  Does anyone have any suggestions for where to look online?  Or do I need to contact JPL or some other agency directly?  I'm also entertaining the idea of ASTER, but am finding those data to be equally challenging to locate.

Where can I find SRTM DSMs? - ResearchGate. Available from: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Where_can_I_find_SRTM_DSMs?tpr_view=K9laIL6pyPlqgwnezqKIxKlevRuyrUeBAiXV_3 [accessed Jan 14, 2016].

I have cross posted because I figure that not everyone uses ResearchGate - https://www.researchgate.net/post/Where_can_I_find_SRTM_DSMs?tpr_view=K9laIL6pyPlqgwnezqKIxKlevRuyrUeBAiXV_3.

Answer (score 2):

The SRTM data *is* a digital surface model as it includes canopy (and buildings and other infrastructure etc), there's further information in this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110755/is-srtm-3-second-arc-free-of-non-terrain-features).

To get a bare earth DEM from SRTM data requires some processing, for example see [Gallant *et al* (2012)](http://www.int-arch-photogramm-remote-sens-spatial-inf-sci.net/XXXIX-B4/275/2012/isprsarchives-XXXIX-B4-275-2012.pdf).

You don't specify what part of the world you want data for, but there is 30m SRTM DSM and DEM data (processed using the Gallant method to remove tree offsets) available under CC-BY for Australia from the [National Elevation Data Framework](http://nedf.ga.gov.au).

For other parts of the world, you can download 30m (1 arc second) void-filled SRTM DSM data from [USGS EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/).

Comment: Thanks for the useful response. These are really good leads. I'd vote you up more than just 1 point if I could. I got a similar response from a USGS employee that I e-mailed, and was able to find and download a DSM (I used the USGS/NASA https://lpdaac.usgs.gov site), process it, and subtract it from NED data in the USA to get a canopy height model. Unfortunately, it seems that SRTM data is really sensitive to slope and aspect so a simple subtraction doesn't quite get at it (although the CHM was able to identify all of the major tall building in Reno, NV, USA where I live). In Nevada, USA most

Answer (score 0):

ALOS World has that data.

The metadata is described here this link.
https://portal.opentopography.org/datasetMetadata?otCollectionID=OT.112016.4326.2

This is the link you can download data worldwide.
https://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/ALOS/en/dataset/aw3d30/aw3d30_e.htm